# I accidentally summoned way too many entities, now the world won't load

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I messed up when typing a command into a repeating command block, and accidentally summoned a bunch of armor stands, all of which were being executed to summon fire arrows every tick. There were so many entities that the world lagged to 0 fps, and I had to exit the game. I now can't get back into the world. I have heard that I can use NBTExplorer to go into the region file to delete the entities manually, but the problem is that I don't know what chunk they are in, and I have loaded way too many chunks to just comb through them all and find the specific one I'm looking for. Is there some way I can find out what chunk has the most entities, or is there some other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NBTExplorer](https://github.com/jaquadro/NBTExplorer/releases) to delete the entities.

The chunks are saved in region files that are named after the coordinates divided by 512, in the folders `region` for Overworld, `DIM-1/region` for Nether and `DIM1/region` for End. Close the world in Minecraft, open the corresponding file in NBTExplorer, navigate to the chunk (here NBTExplorer tells you the coordinates), delete all entries in the `Level.Entities` tag (or just some, if you want) and save.

Comment: The problem is that I can't get into the world (it simply won't load due to how many entities there are), so I don't know the coordinates or chunk coordinates of the problematic area. Is there some way I could find out which chunk the entities are in without going into the world?

Comment: In theory you could look at all the chunks in NBTExplorer. Maybe the region file is actually bigger in file size, but maybe it's not. You could also look at your player coordinates, in another NBT file in `playerdata`, the tag is called `Pos`.

Comment: I was able to look at my co-ords in the Pos tag, find the problematic chunk, and delete all the entities. I can't thank you enough for your help!